# nosetests --with-pylons test.ini => Error: no such option: --with-pylons

Tags: pylons, nosetests

I followed the application to run the tests of pylons project:

http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/i18n/#testing-the-application

But when I run:

```
 nosetests --with-pylons test.ini
```

It reports an error:

```
E:\pylons\helloworld>nosetests --with-pylons test.ini
Usage: nosetests-script.py [options]

nosetests-script.py: error: no such option: --with-pylons
```

Why nosetests doesn't know the `--with-pylons`, how to fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I never used `--with-pylons`. When I am in the directory of the project, `nosetests` does the job without any parameters.

I'm on Linux, with the proper virtualenv activated. Maybe it's different on Windows.

Comment: many thanks to you. It's just because I add virtual env when installing pylons, but not active it when testing. I just deleted the pylons, and use `easy_install pylons`(no virtual env) to install pylons again. This time, `nosetests --with-pylons` works well, and I can test the models now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Pylons 1.0.1, the nose plugin is not registered by Pylons itself any more.

A workaround is to add this to the `entry_points` section of your own project's `setup.py`:

```
[nose.plugins]
pylons = pylons.test:PylonsPlugin
```

Answer (score 3):

This error happens in cases where nose cannot find installed pylons. 
This can happen if nose is installed system-wide (for example, via `apt-get install python-nose`), but Pylons is installed in virtual environment. In that case you can either:

- Install Pylons system-wide, that would pollute your global environment and defeat the purpose of having virtual environment
- Install nose in virtual environment (`easy_install -U nose` when virtual environment is activated)

Comment: That was exactly the case for me. I was surprised, because usually packages I install locally via pip supersede the global distro-installed package, but for nosetests it wasn't the case (`which nosetests`) and I had to `sudo apt-get remove python-nose`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the latest version of pylons using pip, version 1.0.1rc1 is installed. Nose is not able to find the pylons-plugin.

To fix this downgrade to pylons 1.0.

```
pip uninstall pylons
pip install pylons==1.0
```

I had the same problem and found [the solution here](https://github.com/LearningRegistry/LearningRegistry/issues/162)

Comment: Could you add a semi-colon or `&&` between the commands to avoid uninstalling pip by mistake?